# Error: requirements.lock is out of sync with requirements.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have following dependency in requirement.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  - name: redis
    version: 0.1.2
    repository: http://helm-charts.repo:8800/
```

requirements.lock:

```
dependencies:
- name: redis
  repository: http://helm-charts.repo:8800/
  version: 0.1.2
digest: sha256: <some alpha numeric value>
generated: <>
```

---

```
helm dependency build <Chart name>
```

is giving me:

> Error: requirements.lock is out of sync with requirements.yaml

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably have old `digest`. Instead of manually updating `requirements.lock` file use the following command after just updating your `requirement.yaml` file:

```
helm dep update
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar issue

> Error: the lock file (Chart.lock) is out of sync with the dependencies file (Chart.yaml). Please update the dependencies

The problem:
There was `requirements.lock` in the repo and `Chart.lock` got created. This resulted in two lock files and some tools getting confused.

Solution:

```bash
rm requirements.lock
```